# Add tag to an AWS EC2 instance using AWS PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

How do I use the Amazon Web Services (AWS) PowerShell module to add a tag (key-value pair) to an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, install the AWS PowerShell module on PowerShell 5.0 or later:

```
Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Now, go to the IAM console and generate an access key, and use the following command to set your credentials in PowerShell.

```
$AccessKey = '<YourAccessKey>'
$SecretKey = '<SecretKey>'
$Region = 'us-west-1'
Initialize-AWSDefaults -AccessKey $AccessKey -SecretKey $SecretKey -Region $Region
```

Now that you're authenticated from PowerShell, use the following one-liner script to pop open a list of EC2 instances in a WPF window, and select the ones you want to tag.

```
(Get-EC2Instance).Instances | 
  Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple | 
  ForEach-Object -Process { 
    New-EC2Tag -Tag (New-Object -TypeName Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag -ArgumentList @('Key', 'Value')) -Resource $PSItem.InstanceId
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

## PS command

```
New-EC2Tag -ResourceId $Instances -Tags $Tags
```

## From AWS documentation....

```
$tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
$tag.Key = "myTag"
$tag.Value = "myTagValue"

New-EC2Tag -Resource i-12345678 -Tag $tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add more than one tag!

$Tags = @()

$1T=New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag;$1T.key="KEYNAME";$1T.Value="VALUE";$Tags += $1T
$2T=New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag;$2T.key="2ndKEYNAME";$2T.Value="2ndVALUE";$Tags += $2T
$3T=New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag;$3T.key="3rdKEYNAME";$3T.Value="3rdVALUE";$Tags += $3T
$4T=New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag;$4T.key="4thKEYNAME";$4T.Value="4thVALUE";$Tags += $4T
$5T=New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag;$5T.key="5thKEYNAME";$5T.Value="5thVALUE";$Tags += $5T

New-EC2Tag -Resource i-12345678 -Tag $tag